# Reversability of Xor'd Values In Hash?

Tags: hash, known-plaintext-attack

This may be a dumb question so please forgive me if so, but is a hash function considered one-way even if you have half of an xor'd value?

For example say I have the values R and C, both are randomly generated and the same length as the output of the hashing function H, but while R is known C should not be given only R and h below:

```
h = H(C⊕R)
```

Is there any scenario in which you could determine C from h and R or which might reduce the difficulty of brute forcing C in this format to a level you would have to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both values are randomly generated, no, there are no scenarios in which you could determine C from h and R or where your ability to brute force C is made easier by having this information as opposed to just having h.

Answer (score 1):

If it were easy to get `C` from `h` and `R`, you could extend that to a general pre-image attack on `h` by choosing an arbitrary `R` yourself.  Then you get `C` and now you have a pre-image.